# Magento 2 : Receive half payment from customer

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, payment

Can we receive payment in two parts like receive 50% amount once order placed and another 50% once order completed? Also, we need a partial invoice as well.

Is anyone have any idea we can do it.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Payment method is online or offline ?

Comment: we have both offline as well as online

Comment: Ah I see. If you have offline then I could have help you in someways but not in online. You have to check that your online payment method is support partial payments and other things.

Comment: in magento invoice is created like that , you can use the partial payment extension for that